# How to check for a null value in a converter

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I use an SQLDataReader to grab data from my database and instantiate the corresponding Object in code.  I handle all fields that might contain nulls as follows (just a code snippet example):

```
StartDate = If(IsDBNull(rdr(6)), Nothing, rdr.GetDateTime(6)),
```

I use this converter to display the data properly (again using a DateTime field as an example):

```
Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim x As Date = CDate(value)
    Return x.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")
End Function
```

This works fine EXCEPT for those cases where the DateTime field is missing.  In that case I need to check the "value" parameter but no test I've tried works.  I've used IsNothing and IsDBNull.Value.Equals and converting "value" to a string and comparing that to String.Empty.  They all return false, even for fields that have no data (are Null in my database).

Is there a way to check for missing data in the the "value" parameter?

ETA: Here is how I invoke the converter:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DateConverter x:Key="DateConverter">

    </local:DateConverter>
.....
Binding="{Binding Path=ChargeDate, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" />
```

Comment: How do yo call this convert method? What's the use of parameter and targetType in the method?

Comment: Is your app Winforms or WPF?

Comment: `If value Is DBNull.Value Then` the data is null.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya  See my OP edit.

Comment: @Plutonix  WPF  Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney  The compilerrejects that form to check on "value".  I noted in my OP that the correct form gives the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you set a value type, StartDate, to Nothing, which sets it to it's default value.  In this instance, with StartDate being a DateTime, the default value is DateTime.MinValue.  You have a few alternatives for implementing your desired conditional check though.

One, you can use = instead of Is:

```
If value = Nothing Then

End If
```

You could also check for DateTime.MinValue, but if you do I would recommend leveraging your targetType parameter since it would seem that you are trying to make the Convert function generic in nature:

```
If (targetType = GetType(DateTime) AndAlso value = DateTime.MinValue) Then

End If
```

Or StartDate could be a Nullable DateTime, which will make Is Nothing work for you:

```
Dim StartDate as DateTime? = If(IsDBNull(rdr(6)), Nothing, rdr.GetDateTime(6))
```

Comment: The compiler rejects using = when Option Strict is on.  Using the correct syntax gives the wrong answer.  I already set the default value to Nothing and still get the wrong answer.  I have set StartDate to Nullable and it STILL gives the wrong answer.  Finally, I had already thought the only solution was to check for the minimum value but posted this problem because I thought I surely was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

FINAL ANSWER:
I just convert "value" to a date and compare that to an arbitrary date that is before any reasonable input, say, 1800.  If the input is greater than that, I accept it as valid and exit with:

```
Return CDate(value)
```